# Adding custom HTML to each profile group tab

Tags: buddypress, profiles

Hopefully someone can help. I am looking to add a different image banner to each of the profile group tabs I have on my Buddypress site. I have identifed the profile-loop.php as the file I need to include this on but when I try the following code it breaks the profile section of my site:

```
<?php if ( bp_the_profile_group_name() == 'About') ) : ?> 

<h4>Testing</h4>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone suggest how I might target the About group on my site and insert custom HTML?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if i've understood the requirement correctly. Check this link and let me know if that's what is required http://screencloud.net/v/g5kq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have figured out how best to work this. For anyone that may need it sometime the code I used was:

```
<?php if ( 1 == bp_get_the_profile_group_id()) : ?>

<h4>About Me</h4>

<?php endif; ?>
```

With 1 == the profile tab where I need to add my custom HTML. If anyone has a better solution I am open to them. Thanks.